# Proving a linear map is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, linear-transformations, solution-verification

> To prove: A linear operator T on a finite-dimensional vector space V is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an ordered basis $\beta$ for V consisting of eigenvectors of T. If $\beta=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, the corresponding eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. then $[T]_\beta$=$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \\ 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}$

Definition: A linear mapping T on a finite-dimensional vector space V is diagonalizable if there is an ordered basis $\beta$ for V such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

proof: $\Rightarrow$ suppose $\beta=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for V for which $[T]_\beta$ is diagonal, then by definition , we have $[T]_\beta= \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \\ 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}$, then $[T(v_i)]_\beta= [\lambda_i v_i]_\beta$ So $T(v_i)=\lambda_i v_i$ and $\beta$ consists of eigenvectors of T for which $v_i$ $\neq$ 0 by definition.

$\Leftarrow$: suppose $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis consisting of eigenvectors,for V and $T(v_i)$=$\lambda_i v_i$ for all i $(\lambda_i$ $\in F)$, then $T(v_i)=\lambda_i v_i$ for all i $(\lambda_i \in F)$ ,then $T(v_i)=0 v_1+...+\lambda_i v_i+ \dots 0 v_n$ for all i, so $[T]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \\ 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}$.

> Question: Wondering if this makes sense, especially the expression of notations.

Comment: In $\implies$, $\beta$ is not just any basis (but the way you phrase it you allow it to be any basis). Instead, it needs to be a basis for which $[T]_{\beta}$ is diagonal. And then you need to finish showing $v_i$ is an eigenvector. Similarly, in $\Leftarrow$ you need to *pick* $\beta$ to be a basis consisting of eigenvectors, not an arbitrary basis, and show that this means the matrix is diagonal. Your next-to-last equality does not make sense, as $\lambda_iv_i$ is a vector but $[T]_{\beta}$ is a matrix.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you check the revised edition?

Comment: When you write $[T(v_i)]_{\beta}=\lambda_iv_i$, it’s technically incorrect. On the left hand side you have a column vector, on the right hand side an (abstract) vector from $V$. You should also explain why $v_i\neq\mathbf{0}$ (easy). In the $\Leftarrow$ direction, you have $[T]_{\beta}$, a matrix, set equal to a column vector; that’s wrong.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks a lot! I did some revision now. how about now?

Comment: Looks pretty good.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks a lot for the time and effort!